# How can php return a HTML file and value as the response to a POST request?

Tags: php, html

In php file, I put down-drop list and submit button.
Down-drop list show filenames you can choose.
When user chooses filename from down-list drop and push submit button, php should return HTML file as a response.
HTML should show the contents of filename user chose in php file.

How can I implement this system?
At first, I tried to use "readfile" of php, but how can I get filename in html file?

Comment: simple/stupid/highly dangerous: `<?php readfile($_GET['path']); ?>` -> `http://example.com?path=/etc/passwd`

Comment: @MarcB I didn't know where to ask you this but, as you're one of the leading php teachers on SO. I was wondering whether you'd recommend any books?

Comment: @MarcB Exactly :) Thank you! ww

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is not the best answer but you could return the location of your html file stored in a variable then use `include($fileRoute);` or `require_once($fileRoute);`

Comment: that executes the file, which probably isn't a good idea.

Comment: But he does want to show it's contents. Wouldn't it help him out with that too?

Comment: I had not good explanation, so sorry.  The html php should return as response is only one, like "nextpage.html". I want to tell value user chose from drop-down list to nextpage.html. I think it's impossible, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can keep a whitelist of allowed pages in an array, send the array key as a post / get parameter and include the file to display it:

```
$pages =['one.html','two.html','three.html'];
if (isset($_POST['pid']) && isset($pages[$_POST['pid']])){
     include($pages[$_POST['pid']]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for giving your solution for me!